# The number of bytes received in TrafficStats class is smaller than the number of bytes receiverd from inputsream using HTTP

Tags: java, android

I wrote a piece of code to test the available bandwidth of a device using cellular network.

I use `TrafficStats` class to get how many bytes the device have received now, then let the device to download a small file, and finally get how many bytes the device have transferred and the consumed time after downloading.

I set the downloaded file size is 10245 bytes, but the number of `getMobileRxBytes()` after downloading minus `getMobileRxBytes()` before downloading is always lower than 10245 bytes.

I am sure that the cellular network is active and the WiFi is disable, and I got the same result if I use `getTotalRxBytes()` instead.

Here is my code.

```
InputStream inStream = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[10245];
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(DOWNLOAD_RATE_TEST_10KB_URL).openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.connect();
} catch (IOException e) { }

long startingBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
long startingTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

try {
    inStream = connection.getInputStream();
    // Do some busy waiting while the inStream is open.
    while (inStream.read(buffer) != -1) { }
} catch (IOException e) { }

this.elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startingTime;
this.downloadBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() - startingBytes;

try {
    if (inStream != null) { inStream.close(); }
} catch (IOException e) {}
connection.disconnect();
```

Is there a cache issue? Or I use APIs in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You're downloading over HTTP: there may be compression occurring (gzip/deflate) that is transparent to the HTTP connection but reduces the bytes over the wire.

Comment: Sometimes I got full(10245) bytes from inputstream using HTTP, but I got zero bytes in this interval by using TrafficStats class. It's not only the compression occurring, is it?

Comment: By the way, the number of data received by using TrafficStats class varied from 0 to 9XXX bytes, including 0, 1127, 3936, 6795, 8173, 9603, etc. Could the compression ratio of HTTP 1.1 in the same file dynamically change in such a large range ?

Comment: I just used getContentLength()  to see how many bytes will be transfer, and it's 10245 bytes, so there should be no compression occurring.